# How to scrap dynamic HTML table with differencet class name for each row containing nested elements?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors, webdriver

I want to create a dataframe by scrapping the table [here](https://www.egp.gov.bt/resources/common/TenderListing.jsp?lang=en_US&langForMenu=en_US&h=t) which has different `class` name for each row and contains nested elements.

```
table_rows = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "bgColor-white")
for _, val in enumerate(table_rows):
    print(val.text)
```

`Print` output of the above code is string but could not segregate into appropriate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify the table element and then get the `outerHTML` of the table element.
Use pandas `read_html()` method and get the `dataframe`.

```
driver.get ("https://www.egp.gov.bt/resources/common/TenderListing.jsp?lang=en_US&langForMenu=en_US&h=t")
time.sleep(3)
table= driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#resultTable").get_attribute("outerHTML")
df=pd.read_html(table)[0]
print(df)
```

**console output:**

```
   Sl. No.           Tender ID,  Reference No,  Public Status  ... Type,  Method Publishing Date & Time | Closing Date & Time
0        1    15183, TSHA-6/Engineering/9/2022-2023/769, Live  ...     NCB,  OTM        03-Mar-2023 15:00 | 14-Mar-2023 15:10
1        2            15180, STCB/PD/TS/Samtse/2023/213, Live  ...     NCB,  OTM        03-Mar-2023 10:00 | 14-Mar-2023 11:10
2        3            15160, JNEC/Adm-33/2022-2023, Cancelled  ...     NCB,  OTM        02-Mar-2023 22:00 | 10-Mar-2023 10:30
3        4          15179,  DAG/DEHSS(07)/2022-2023/148, Live  ...     NCB,  OTM        02-Mar-2023 15:00 | 16-Mar-2023 09:00
4        5  15181, DCHS/PRP-01/2022-2023/244, Amendment/Co...  ...     NCB,  OTM        02-Mar-2023 09:00 | 13-Mar-2023 10:30
5        6                  15174, NBC/Adm/06/2022/1198, Live  ...     NCB,  OTM        01-Mar-2023 09:00 | 20-Mar-2023 11:30
6        7                15161, PDA/adm -35/2022-2023/, Live  ...     NCB,  OTM        27-Feb-2023 16:00 | 10-Mar-2023 11:00
7        8  15169,  MD/Dz.EHSS-20/2022-2023/5179, Amendmen...  ...     NCB,  OTM        27-Feb-2023 14:30 | 10-Mar-2023 14:00
8        9                                 15157, nofp2, Live  ...     NCB,  OTM        21-Feb-2023 09:00 | 08-Mar-2023 11:30
9       10   15158, MD/DES-20/2022-2023/5095, Being processed  ...     NCB,  OTM        21-Feb-2023 02:00 | 02-Mar-2023 10:00

[10 rows x 6 columns]
```